# jQuery ui droppable hoverClass activeClass

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, droppable, jquery-hover

I have this code

```
$( "div.column_14_int" ).droppable({
  accept: "div.element-container",
  activeClass: "drop-cl",    
  hoverClass: "drag-over",
  tolerance: 'pointer',
  greedy: true,

    drop: function( event, ui ) {
   $(ui.draggable).appendTo( this );
    },

});
```

That works fine, but when start dragging an item, the activeClass is added to droppable and work.

When draggable item is over droppable hoverClass is added to droppable, but it doesn't work: the droppable element still has the activeClass color.

draggable item

```
<div class='element-container delete_el w4-4'>\
<div class='element-handler'>\
<a href='#edit-element' class='edit revs-edit-element'>Edit</a>\
<a href='#del' class='del-element'>X</a>\
</div><div class='element'>\
<span class='element-icon'>\
<img src='http://placehold.it/36x36&text=icon'></span>\
<span class='element-name'>Element name</span></div>\
<textarea rows='4' cols='20' class='text-shortcode'>[revs_flexslider page='home']    
</textarea>\
</div>"
```

droppable

```
 <div class='column_14 column_del column '><div class='top-bar'><div class='left
 controllers'><a href='#decr' class='decr'>-</a><span class='sz'>1/4</span><a    
 href='#incr' class='decr'>+</a></div><div class='del-column'><input type='button'  
 class='del' value='X'></div></div><div class='pb-element-container column_14_int 
 column_control connectedSortable'></div><textarea rows='4' cols='20' class='text-
 shortcode text-shortcode-col'>[rev-column whidt='14']</textarea></div>
```

But i dont know Why u need thi for answer

Comment: Could you include your html?

Comment: just included But i dont know Why u need thi for answer

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should probably do is to check your console to see if your hover and active classes are actually added to the object. If they are, then the problem is most likely to do with your CSS specificity.

To fix, either:

1. Rearrange your CSS declarations such that drop-cl comes before drag-over (assuming they have the same CSS specificity), or
2. Change the specificity of the drag-over by adding ids/classes/etc (or !important)

Here's a nice article on [CSS Specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)